# How to access funds from selling NFT on OpenSea.io when paid via internal transaction sent to my MetaMask Wallet?

Tags: metamask, wallets, nft, internal-transactions, opensea

I sold an NFT on OpenSea.io but don't see the proceeds reflected in my MetaMask wallet. Upon review, OpenSea sent the proceeds of the sale via internal transaction to my MetaMask wallet. How do I access these proceeds?

Answer (score 1):

Is this from an NFT you minted and then sold - or just sold?
If you sold the NFT by accepting an offer, it would be in wETH so make sure you look on the Polygon/MATIC side of your wallet (https://wallet.matic.network/)

If you minted and then sold, double check in your creator tools what address you linked to send it to. It would also be cool to post the TX here :)